# Matrices en Matlab: ¿qué significa A(1:M-1,j)?

Tags: python, matrices, matlab

¿Qué significa `A(1:n,j)` en Matlab?

¿Cómo lo escribo en Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un slicing o rebanado de una matriz bidimencional, dónde obtienes las  `n` primeras filas y la columna `j`. Un ejemplo es más descriptivo:

```
>> A = [1 2 3 4 5; 6 7 8 9 10; 11 12 13 14 15; 16 17 18 19 20];
>> A
A =

    1    2    3    4    5
    6    7    8    9   10
   11   12   13   14   15
   16   17   18   19   20

>> n = 3
>> j = 2

>> A(1:n,j)
ans =

    2
    7
   12
```

Como se puede observar se selecciona las filas desde la 1 hasta la 3 (incluidas) con `1:n` (`1:3`), luego se toma la segunda columna.

Lo normal es que estés usando NumPy en Python, en este caso la sintaxis es muy similar pero con algunas diferencias importantes:

- Aunque en este caso no se usa el parámetro `step` explícitamente, hay que tener en cuenta que en Matlab la sintaxis general es `start:step:end` mientras que en NumPy es `start:end:step`.
- En Python el indexado empieza en 0 (*0 based indexing*) mientras que en Matlab el indexado empieza en 1 (*1 based indexing*). Esto significa que la primera fila/columna/elemento... de una matriz tiene índice 0 en Python e índice 1 en Matlab.
- En Python se usa `[]` en vez de `()` a la hora de indexar.
- Cuando se hace un slicing, el índice final del rango no se incluye en Python pero si en Matlab. Es decir, en Matlab `A(1:3)` incluye la tercera columna, pero Python `A[0:2]` no incluye la tercera columna (debería ser `A[0:3]` para ello, recordando que el índice 3 se corresponde con la cuarta columna).

Por lo tanto el equivalente en NumPy sería `A[0:n, j-1]`, podemos verlo con el mismo ejemplo:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([[1,   2,  3,  4,  5],
                  [6,   7,  8,  9, 10],
                  [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
                  [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]])

>>> n = 3
>>> j = 2

>>> A[0:n, j-1]
array([ 2,  7, 12])
```

Lo normal como digo es que se use [NumPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/) si se quiere trabajar de forma vectorizada con matrices al estilo de Matlab. no obstante, se puede hacer los mismo con listas normales de Python, aunque se complica algo. En este caso podemos hacerlo usando una lista por compresión:

```
>>> A = [[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
         [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
         [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
         [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]]

>>> n = 3
>>> j = 2

>>> [row[j-1] for row in A[0:n]]
[2, 7, 12]
```

Puedes mirarte la documentación de Matlab y de NumPy al respecto del slicing para más información:

- [Matlab -> Indexación de arreglos](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/array-indexing.html)
- [NumPy -> Indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)